# GraphQL laravel lighthouse and vue deploy error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, graphql, syntax-error, web-deployment

I am using graphql with vuejs and laravel and it was working well on my local env but i am getting `Syntax Error: Unexpected` after i launched it on the live server.

Does anyone facing this issue and do you know how to solve it?

```
Uncaught Error: [
  {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>",
        "extensions": {
          "category": "graphql"
        },
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 1,
            "column": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
    at Object.next (SchemaFetcher.ts:136)
    at b (Observable.js:135)
    at E (Observable.js:179)
    at e.value (Observable.js:235)
    at bundle.esm.js:76
```

[image: Error]

```
 APP_NAME="HLH EXPRESS"
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_URL=http://hlhexpress.xyz
    
    LOG_CHANNEL=stack
    
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=
    DB_USERNAME=
    DB_PASSWORD=
    
    BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
    CACHE_DRIVER=file
    QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
    SESSION_DRIVER=file
    #SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
    SESSION_LIFETIME=120
    
    REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
    REDIS_PASSWORD=null
    REDIS_PORT=6379
    
    MAIL_MAILER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME=null
    MAIL_PASSWORD=null
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
    
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    AWS_BUCKET=
    
    PUSHER_APP_ID=
    PUSHER_APP_KEY=
    PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
    PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
    
    MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
    MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
    
    
    # production
    SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="hlhexpress.xyz"
    #SESSION_DOMAIN=".hlhexpress.xyz"
```

Comment: Can you post the error as text rather then screenshot please?

Comment: Unexpected EOF might mean the file was corrupted during transfer. EOF means end of file. Finding EOF at line 1 column 1 as error suggests something went really wrong

Comment: Hi @Ruli
I found it and just adding backslash into my api URI. and i am not 100% sure why it's a difference between / and non(/)

Comment: Hi @loa_in_ I found it and just adding backslash into my api URI. and i am not 100% sure why it's a difference between / and non(/)

Comment: Oh. Some libraries need trailing slash and some don't. Glad you found out! Feel free to remove the question as it's not a question that can help someone else - since your problem wasn't relevant to details here